# Finding a path in a graph with random edges

Tags: c++, graph, tree, depth-first-search

We have n vertices (where n is less than 100 000) and m random edges (where m is less than 10 000 000). We want to find a path between 2 given vertices. If there is no path we will just print -1.
My algorithm is to build a tree. Every vertex has a disjoint_index (i) which shows that all vertices with disjoint_index (i), are connected.

The default value of disjoint_index is the index of each vertex. After finding an edge between vertex v and u, I check if they are connected. If they are connected, I do nothing. Else I change the disjoint_index of u and all the vertices connected to u by a function named (dfs).

Here is the code of the function to build this tree in c++:

```
struct vertex{
    int disjoint_index;
    vector<int> adjacent;
};

void build_tree(int m, int s, int e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int u = kiss() % n;
        int v = kiss() % n;

        if(disjoint_counter[u] > disjoint_counter[v])
        {
            int temp = u;
            u = v;
            v = temp;
        }//counter v > u

        if(ver[v].disjoint_index != ver[u].disjoint_index)
        {
            ver[v].adjacent.push_back(u);
            ver[u].adjacent.push_back(v);

            dfs(v, u, ver[v].disjoint_index);

            disjoint_counter[v] += disjoint_counter[u];
        }

        if(ver[s].disjoint_index == ver[e].disjoint_index)
            return;
    }
}

void dfs(int parent, int v, int d)
{
    ver[v].disjoint_index = d;
    for(int i = 0; i < ver[v].adjacent.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ver[v].adjacent[i] == parent)
            continue;
        dfs(v, ver[v].adjacent[i], d);
    }
}
```

Here you can skip kiss, It's just a function that returns two vertices and shows that there is an edge between u and v.

disjoint_counter[i] shows how many vertices are in connected group i.

After building this tree I will find a path with a simple dfs. The time limit is 1s and I get Time Limit Exceeded on some test cases.

Edit: Memory is limited so I can't save all the edges.
Maximum memory I can use is 32MB.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need to build a tree in order to find a path between two vertices? What's wrong with BFS?

Comment: There are 10 000 000 edges and they are completely random, so I have to rerun the for loop each time to find adjacent vertices of each vertex, worse case scenario, It will take 100 000 times which is much slower than my current algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the edges are random? Are you not given the edges in the graph?

Comment: When I call kiss function, It gives me 2 vertices and there is an edge between them. Sorry I forgot to say that my memory is limited and I can't save all edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the disjoint set union algorithm, it developed speed.